# Silent install application using KUDU on Windows Cloud

Tags: windows, cloud, kudu

My web application is deployed on windows cloud. 
Now I want to install one exe file on server.
I can install that exe file silently on my local machine using command prompt.

but when I execute same command on KUDU command prompt. It is not installing. no error shown.

I have uploaded my exe to wwwroot folder on cloud server and I have checked paths in my command. everything is correct.

In local I have to run command prompt as administrator to install my exe. I think this is the same issue with KUDU command prompt.

How can I run KUDU command prompt as administrator